# Google Analytics | Multiple Exact Matches In Advanced Filter

Tags: filter, google-analytics

I have results for `FOOD, FOOD20 and FOOD 30` but have other results that come from `FOOD` such as `DOGFOOD, CATFOOD` using REGEX.

I am trying to place an EXACT filter by using:-

```
FOOD|FOOD20|FOOD30
```

to extract just these results instead of using REGEX. Unfortunately this is returning 0 results.

Is there another work around for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it iz not about programming. Try on webmasters.

Answer (score 3):

An exact filter is a literal string match, so you're explicitly looking for something matching all of "FOOD|FOOD20|FOOD30" exactly.

If you want to ensure that the value is exactly `FOOD`, `FOOD20` or `FOOD30`, use REGEX matching, but precede each value with a caret (`^`), which marks the beginning of the line, and follow each value with the dollar sign (`$`), which marks the end of the line.

So, your REGEX expression would be:

```
^FOOD$|^FOOD20$|^FOOD30$
```

If your idea is to track anything that starts with "FOOD", followed by a number, and then ends, you can simplify your expression to the following:

```
^FOOD[0-9]*$
```

(The [0-9]* part means match the numbers 0 to 9 zero or more times, so it matches when there are no numbers after `FOOD`, or when there are some.)

This will match `FOOD`, `FOOD20`, `FOOD30`, `FOOD99` and `FOOD100`, but not `CATFOOD`, `DOGFOOD10`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. You were very helpful.